# if $f:X \to Y$ is 1-1 and $|X| = |Y|$, does that imply $f$ is onto?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Similarly, if $f$ is onto and both sets have the same cardinality, does that imply $f$ is 1-1? I'm pretty sure both statements are true but I'd rather not assume.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: Not if the cardinality is infinite.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not if $X$ and $Y$ are infinite: the map $f:\Bbb N\to\Bbb Z:n\mapsto n$ is $1$-$1$, and $|\Bbb N|=|\Bbb Z|$, but $f$ is not onto. For the other question, let $g:\Bbb Z\to\Bbb N:n\mapsto|n|$: then $g$ is onto but not $1$-$1$.

Both statements are true if the sets are finite, however.

Comment: How can you prove those statements are true for finite sets? 

It seems obvious but I'm kinda lost on the proof.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD: That depends very much on how formal you want to be and how you’ve defined *finite*.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD I wrote up a proof for one of the statements in my answer just now.

Comment: @TrevorWilson Thanks! I'll read it in a moment.

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed out, this is true for finite sets and not for infinite sets. (In fact, a set $X$ is infinite if and only if there is a 1-1 function from $X$ to itself that is not onto, although the proof of the forward direction requires a fragment of the Axiom of Choice.)

For finite sets, the statement can be proved by induction on the cardinality of the sets:

- The base case is trivial because every function between $0$-element sets (*i.e.* from the empty set to itself) is onto. There is only one function to consider, namely the empty function.
- Now suppose that every 1-1 function between $n$-element sets is onto, and let $f: X \to Y$ be a 1-1 function between sets $X$ and $Y$ with $n+1$ elements. We want to show that $f$ is onto.  Take any $a \in X$.  Then the restriction $f \restriction (X \setminus \{a\})$ is a 1-1 function from $X \setminus \{a\}$ to $Y \setminus \{f(a)\}$.  (Note that we need that $f$ is 1-1 just to see that the restriction maps *into* the stated codomain.)  By the induction hypothesis, the restriction $f \restriction (X \setminus \{a\})$ is onto $Y \setminus \{f(a)\}$, which implies that the original function $f$ is onto $Y$.

Comment: What does the arrow between $f$ and $X$ mean?

Comment: It means that we are restricting the function $f$ to the set which follows (*e.g.* $X \setminus \{a\}$.)  I should probably add parentheses.

Comment: I see, that would be "bounding" the domain, right?
Also, are you using "\" in $X$ \ $\{a\}$ for difference? Sorry, I'm not used to that notation.

Comment: Yes, I guess you could call it that, although to me "bounding" would suggest that some order relation was involved.  And yes, I am using "$\setminus$" for set difference.  (I don't like to use "$-$" for this because in some contexts it could be confused with the set of algebraic differences of elements of the two sets.)

Answer (score 2):

In fact, for finite sets that is a good way to prove 1-1.

It also works the other way:  If $X, Y$ are sets of the same finite cardinality, and if $f : X \to Y$ is 1-1, then $f$ us onto.

**Other variants:**
If $X, Y$ are vector spaces of the same finite dimension, and $f : X \to Y$ is linear and onto, then $f$ is 1-1.

If $X, Y$ are sets, $|X| > |Y|$ (finite or infinite) and $f : X \to Y$, then $f$ is not 1-1.

If $X, Y$ are sets, $|X| < |Y|$ (finite or infinite) and $f : X \to Y$, then $f$ is not onto.

Comment: The fact that every 1-1 function between finite sets of the same cardinality is onto is useful in proving things like the Chinese remainder theorem and that every finite integral domain is a field; I'd be curious to know what applications you have in mind for going the other way (from onto to 1-1).

Comment: The second of your three variants (in the infinite case) is often taken to be a definition rather than a theorem: we say $|X| \le |Y|$ iff there is a 1-1 function from $X$ to $Y$.  (Also I can't help but point out that the third of your three variants can fail in the infinite case if we do not assume the Axiom of Choice, which is pretty bizarre in my opinion.)

Answer (score 1):

True if X and Y are finite. Consider X and Y are N: f(n) = n +1